# ingest data to google cloud data catalog

Tags: python, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am trying to use the google-datacatalog-postgresql-connector to ingest some data into data catalog that I have exported to a csv file from a postgres data base. my environment is windows 10

I have moved the csv file to a GCS bucket and I have defined the following environment variables

```
 POSTGRESQL2DC_DATACATALOG_LOCATION_ID=us-central
 POSTGRESQL2DC_DATACATALOG_PROJECT_ID=cps-sandbox
 POSTGRESQL2DC_POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=demo
 POSTGRESQL2DC_POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxx
 POSTGRESQL2DC_POSTGRESQL_SERVER=xxxxxxxx
```

POSTGRESQL2DC_POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=postgres
POSTGRESQL2DC_RAW_METADATA_CSV=gs://cb10-bucket/meta_1.csv

when I run the connector with the following command

```
 google-datacatalog-postgresql-connector ^
 --datacatalog-project-id=$POSTGRESQL2DC_DATACATALOG_PROJECT_ID ^
 --datacatalog-location-id=$POSTGRESQL2DC_DATACATALOG_LOCATION_ID ^
 --postgresql-host=$POSTGRESQL2DC_POSTGRESQL_SERVER ^
 --postgresql-user=$POSTGRESQL2DC_POSTGRESQL_USERNAME  ^
 --postgresql-pass=$POSTGRESQL2DC_POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD ^
 --postgresql-database=$POSTGRESQL2DC_POSTGRESQL_DATABASE ^
 --raw-metadata-csv=$POSTGRESQL2DC_RAW_METADATA_CSV
```

I receive the following error:

```
   File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
   File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 674, in 
   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '$POSTGRESQL2DC_RAW_METADATA_CSV'
```

I am confused as the POSTGRESQL2DC_RAW_METADATA_CSV=gs://cb1-bucket1/meta_1.csv id defined and I have tried defining it as POSTGRESQL2DC_RAW_METADATA_CSV='gs://cb10-bucket/meta_1.csv'
but I get the same error

I should also point out that my GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable is set to my credentials .json file

what am I missing?